# How do I extract more data through Google Analytics Embed Api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I followed [1]: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/ to embed google analytics into my website admin dashboard. This demo working fine. But I want extract other google analytics then this. Just like I want to add bounce rate,Social Media analytics etc. How i write the code for it just like in demo.

Comment: welcome to stack you need to show us what you have tried and explain any issues you are having with your implementation.

Comment: Thanks. If you see the link I tried same demo and its working fine. What my question is this how i can embed more charts other then describe in demo..